# text/template issue Parse() vs. ParseFiles()

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm trying to do some simple work with the text/template package.  The sample given at the top of [template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) is what I'm working with.

How do I write the 'parsed' file so `template.ParseFiles()` properly reads and executes it?

```
package main

import (
    "text/template"
    "os"
)

type Inventory struct {
    Material string
    Count    uint
}

func main() {
    sweaters := Inventory{"wool", 17}
    tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse("{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}")
    // tmpl, err := template.New("test").ParseFiles("file.txt")

    if err != nil { panic(err) }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, sweaters)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }
}

/*
Contents of file.txt:
{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}

Error thrown:
panic: template: test:1: "test" is an incomplete or empty template

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/templates/t.go:19 +0x21a

goroutine 2 [syscall]:
created by runtime.main
    /var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/go-1.0.1/work/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221
*/
```

I have a copy of this code posted at the golang playground [here](http://play.golang.org/p/C3oTaFFRmp)

Edit #1:
I've been doing some research on this issue... since it's the `Execute()` method that actually throws the exception, and not the `ParseFiles()` part, I checked the method definition:

```
// Execute applies a parsed template to the specified data object,
// and writes the output to wr.
func (t *Template) Execute(wr io.Writer, data interface{}) (err error) {
    defer errRecover(&err)
    value := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    state := &state{
        tmpl: t,
        wr:   wr,
        line: 1,
        vars: []variable{{"$", value}},
    }
    if t.Tree == nil || t.Root == nil {
        state.errorf("%q is an incomplete or empty template", t.name)
    }
    state.walk(value, t.Root)
    return
}
```

So, on a hunch, I dumped the value of t.Tree for the inline 'non-file' style, tmpl is: `&parse.Tree{Name:"test", Root:(*parse.ListNode)(0xf840030700), funcs:[]map[string]interface {}(nil), lex:(*parse.lexer)(nil), token:[2]parse.item{parse.item{typ:6, val:""}, parse.item{typ:9, val:"{{"}}, peekCount:1, vars:[]string(nil)}` and
 when ran with `ParseFiles()`, tmpl is: `(*parse.Tree)(nil)`.  I find it odd that one is a dereference, and one value is a pointer.  This may help solve the riddle

Comment: Note, the interesting thing about this example, and other `ParseFiles()` tests I've done, they don't fail on parsing, they fail when they get to the Execute() phase, always with the **incomplete or empty template** message

Comment: Your linked golang playground example works for me. Are you sure this is actually broken?

Comment: Yes, it works fine, because you don't have access to a filesystem on the playground.  However, if you uncomment the `ParseFiles()` line, comment out the other `Parse()` line run it locally, you'll see the error that I have in the comments in the code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sweaters := Inventory{"wool", 17}
tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("file.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "file.txt", sweaters)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

If you have many files, you can use ParseGlob:

```
tmpl, err := template.ParseGlob("*.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "file.txt", sweaters)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "file2.txt", sweaters)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Yup, I actually found that answer myself later on, but stackoverflow would not let me post it.  It is confusing and unfortunate that while `Parse()` works in a similar fashion to `(t *Template) Parse()`, `ParseFiles()` works in a different way than `(t *Template) ParseFiles()` which caused all of my confusion.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: Key point: use template.ParseFiles("filename.txt"), NOT (t *Template) ParseFiles... and I will never get the last hour back again.

Comment: @EvanPlumlee: Ran into the same issue and your comment is what cleared it up for me. Don't think I would have found it otherwise. Had to look at the pkg docs again.

Comment: Additionally, if your template is in a subdirectory the argument to ExecuteTemplate is the file name part only *without* the path to the directory.

Comment: `template.ParseFiles("file.txt")` returns a Template named `file.txt`. Therefore when you execute `template.New("test").ParseFiles("file.txt")` you end up with 2 Templates: `test` and `file.txt`. The latter is _associated_ with the former.

Answer (score 11):

There is a little trick in Go template parseFiles.

```
func parseFiles(t *Template, filenames ...string) (*Template, error) {
    if len(filenames) == 0 {
        // Not really a problem, but be consistent.
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("template: no files named in call to ParseFiles")
    }
    for _, filename := range filenames {
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        s := string(b)
        name := filepath.Base(filename)
        // First template becomes return value if not already defined,
        // and we use that one for subsequent New calls to associate
        // all the templates together. Also, if this file has the same name
        // as t, this file becomes the contents of t, so
        //  t, err := New(name).Funcs(xxx).ParseFiles(name)
        // works. Otherwise we create a new template associated with t.
        var tmpl *Template
        if t == nil {
            t = New(name)
        }
        if name == t.Name() {
            tmpl = t
        } else {
            tmpl = t.New(name)
        }
        _, err = tmpl.Parse(s)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return t, nil
}
```

Only the template with same name will be reuse, otherwise create new one.
as your sample:

```
tmpl, err := template.New("test").ParseFiles("file.txt")
```

tmpl is the template named "test", and associated another template named "file.txt", you call Execute on "test" template, this template is a empty template, so raise the error "test is an incomplete or empty template".

It worked when you change the template name to file.txt

```
tmpl, err := template.New("file.txt").ParseFiles("file.txt")
```

Comment: this is what make it suck, ignore the template defined name and use the filename instead